# Problem with larg index when testing my code

Tags: list, haskell, testing

I am trying to learn Haskell, I want to write a recursive function and do not use any library functions. The function

```
nth ::Integer -> [a ] -> Maybe a
```

takes an index n and a list of elements and returns the n-th element of the list (if the index is valid) or Nothing if
the index is invalid.

My code:

```
nth :: Integer -> [a] -> Maybe a
nth a [] = Nothing
nth a (x:xs) |a == 1 = Just x 
             |fromIntegral (length xs) < a = Nothing 
             |a==0 = Nothing
             | otherwise = nth (a-1) xs
```

I want to do this test to my code:

```
spec = do

    describe "nth" $ do
        it "for valid indexes it behaves like (!!)" $
            property $ \n xs -> n < 0 || (fromInteger n) >= length (xs::[Integer]) || Lists.nth n xs == Just (xs!!(fromInteger n))
        it "for negative indexes it returns Nothing" $
            property $ \n xs -> n >= 0 || Lists.nth n (xs::[Integer]) == Nothing
        it "for too large indexes it returns Nothing" $
            property $ \n xs -> (fromInteger n) < length xs || Lists.nth n (xs::[Integer]) == Nothing
```

but every time I am doing the test I'm getting an error

```
  for valid indexes it behaves like (!!) FAILED [1]
    for negative indexes it returns Nothing
      +++ OK, passed 100 tests.
    for too large indexes it returns Nothing FAILED [2]

1) Lists.nth for valid indexes it behaves like (!!)
       Falsified (after 5 tests and 5 shrinks):
         0
         [0]

  To rerun use: --match "/Lists/nth/for valid indexes it behaves like (!!)/"

  ./ListsSpec.hs:23:9: 
  2) Lists.nth for too large indexes it returns Nothing
       Falsified (after 38 tests):
         1
         [0]
```

Comment: You realize that your `length xs` in your function definition is one less than the length of the list, since you here calculate the length of the tail, right?

Comment: I unsure why `Just x` is being returned from `a=1` instead of from `a=0`? Or was this an attempt at implementing 1-based indexing... :P

Comment: @TrebledJ: that is my idea yes. That is not *per se* a problem. It would definitely make it a bit more challenging.

Comment: Why does your `nth a (x:xs)` part have 4 different conditions/branches? There should be only 2.

Comment: I would simply remove the `length` check entirely. The recursive case should mean all attempts to access a too-large index will eventually come to taking the index of an empty list, which you've already covered. And computing the length at each recursive step will make this function exceptionally slow.

Comment: @melpomene I wanted to check if the index I'm getting is negative so I don't have to check anything and I would get the nothing immediately.

Comment: @Dania If anything, that should happen at an outer layer. There's no need to check for negative indices at every single step of the algorithm.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, you are probably right I shouldn't use the length function I wanted to see if the index is just bigger than the length of the List but I can do it by using the recursive function.

Comment: @melpomene yes, you are right it will slow the run time. I've changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems here with your function. The reason why the first case (behaving like `(!!)`) fails, is because `(!!) :: Int -> [a] -> a` uses a zero-based index, whereas your function seems to work with a one-based index. That means that you will thus need to decrement the index you give to the function.

Furthermore in your function you make a a comparison between `n` and `fromIntegral (length xs)`. Since `xs` is the *tail* of the list, the check is not correct since it will, in certain circumstances, never consider the last element. Indeed:

```
Prelude> nth 2 [0, 2]
Nothing
```

Furthermore it is typically *not* a good idea to use `length` in *each* iteration. `length` runs in *O(n)*, that means that your algorithm now runs in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, so as the list grows, this easily will start taking considerable time.

A shorter and more elegant way to fix this is probably:

```
nth :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> Maybe a
nth 1 (x:_) = Just x
nth i (_:xs) | i < 1 = Nothing
             | otherwise = nth (i-1) xs
nth _ [] = Nothing
```

Here we thus have four cases: in case the index is `1` and the list is non-empty, we return the head of the list, wrapped in a `Just`. If the index is not one, and it is less than one, then the index is too small, and hence we return `Nothing` (this case is strictly speaking not necessary). If `i` is greater than one, then we call `nth (i-1) xs`. Finally if we have reached the end of the list (or the list was empty in the first place), we return `Nothing` as well).

Now in order to test this, we thus need to rewrite these three cases:

```
describe "nth" $ do
    it "for valid indexes it behaves like (!!)" $
        property $ \n xs -> n <= 0 || n > length (xs :: [Integer]) || Lists.nth n xs == Just (xs !! (n-1))
    it "for negative indexes it returns Nothing" $
        property $ \n xs -> n > 0 || Lists.nth n (xs :: [Integer]) == Nothing
    it "for too large indexes it returns Nothing" $
        property $ \n xs -> n <= length xs || Lists.nth n (xs :: [Integer]) == Nothing
```

The first one thus excludes `n <= 0` (negative or zero indices) as well as `n > length xs` and thus checks if the value is `Just (xs !! (n-1))`.

In the second case excludes values greater than zero, and checks if all remaining indices map on `Nothing`.

Finally the last property checks that for values that are higher than `length xs`, we obtain nothing as well.

Note that here `nth` uses one-based indexing. I leave it as an exercise to make it zero-based.

Comment: Actually, I am not allowed to change the specification part because it is a part of the question. I've changed the code the way you wrote it, however, I am getting the same failure with big indices. it should actually work because if I try it without using the test it gives me "Nothing" if I try for example nth 1000 [1,2,3]

Comment: @Dania: you realize that since this is one-based, the bounds of the test should be sligly different?

Comment: yes, in my test they are testing the zero-based. I changed my code now to this: `nth :: Integer -> [a] -> Maybe a
nth 0 (x:_) = Nothing 
nth 1 (x:_) = Just x
nth a (_:xs) |a < 0 = Nothing 
|otherwise = nth (a-1) xs 
nth _ [] = Nothing`

Comment: @Dania: but that is insufficient to make it zero-based.

Comment: it works now `nth :: Integer -> [a] -> Maybe a nth 0 (x:_) = Just x nth a (_:xs) |a < 0 = Nothing |otherwise = nth (a-1) xs nth _ [] = Nothing`  thanks

Comment: @chi: somehow after rereading, I think "phase" here does not make much sense either. Modified it to "in each iteration". Thanks.